# Django SSLRedirect non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, django, ssl, middleware

I am trying to to redirect some of my Django views to https, using the [SSLRedirect](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/) middleware.

I created the middleware, but I'm having trouble securing specific url paths as described in the middleware snippet. When I add `{'SSL':True}` to my view keywords, I get this syntax error: 'non-keyword arg after keyword arg'. My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from post.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    url(r'^$', turk_post, name='post', {'SSL':True}),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
url(r'^$', turk_post, name='post', {'SSL':True}),
```

with:

```
url(r'^$', turk_post, name='post', kwargs={'SSL':True}),
```

The Django `url` is a function defined like this:

```
def url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix=''):
    # et cetera
```

*(hence your error as the function expects a keyword argument)*